# Tab Bar Height appears 2X larger than it should

Tags: xcode

I have a TableView Controller embedded in a Navigation Controller which is embedded in a Tab Bar Controller.

For some reason the Tab Bar Height is twice the size of what is is supposed to be.  I am using Interface Builder settings and have am not interacting with the Tab Bar directly with code.

Could this be any issue with Auto Layout?  Thoughts please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how I did this, but there was a toolbar in my Navigation Controller.  I deleted it and this fixed the issue.